# Jquery : Replacement of accented characters on h2

Tags: jquery, replace, special-characters

I try to replace special characters I've defined which are contained on all my < h2 >

I've wrote this piece of code but it still not work.

```
   var charMap = {
    à:'a',è:'e',é:'e',ä:'a',ë:'e',
    ö:'o',â:'a',À:'A',É:'E',È:'E',
};
$('h2').each(function() {
        var str = $(this).text() ;

        var str_array = str.split('');

        for( var i = 0, len = str_array.length; i < len; i++ ) {
            str_array[ i ] = charMap[ str_array[ i ] ] || str_array[ i ];
        };
    });
```

Thanks for helping newbie like me :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll have to actually *set* the new value too:

```
...
for( var i = 0, len = str_array.length; i < len; i++ ) {
    str_array[ i ] = charMap[ str_array[ i ] ] || str_array[ i ];
};
$(this).text(str_array.join(''));
```

where the builtin function `Array.join` is effectively the "inverse" of `String.split`.